# Angular 5 CLI 3rd party libraries by link

Tags: angular

I'm curious about including 3rd party library via `.angular-cli.json`. I've managed how to include libraries from `node_modules`, but how to add library from CDN is a mystery for me.
Right now my imports look so

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      ],
```

However, inserting URI breaks the compilations

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. If you want to load some resource from CDN you need to put URL in your `index.html`.

See also: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6887